# How to limit CPU and memory usage for node processes

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, ghost-blog

I would like to [install a Ghost Blog on a shared server via GitHub](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost#developer-install-from-git). During the installation, I need to run `npm install, grunt init` and `grunt prod`. My host provides 500 MB memory usage, if a process uses more than 600 MB it kills it.

Therefore I need an option to limit the memory usage of these processes because they all need more than 500 MB of memory!

I tried to run the processes with `--max-old-space-size=450` but it does not seem to work.

I would be glad if anyone could provide me a link to a tutorial or documentation about running node processes with options.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Since I’ve posted this the installation of Ghost has changed completely.

Comment: If your host OS is linux you can use cgroups to limit memory usage of ANY process.

Comment: cgroups isn’t in stalled, and i am not allowed to install it. But thank you!

Comment: slebetman could you give an example of how to use cgroups to limit memory usage of a process?

Comment: So nothing for CPU?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From node v8+, typing the following:

```
node --help
```

show a --v8-options option. Then typing:

```
node --v8-options
```

gives:

```
...
--max_old_space_size (max size of the old space (in Mbytes))
    type: int  default: 0
--initial_old_space_size (initial old space size (in Mbytes))
    type: int  default: 0
...
```

I have managed to use the first option like this:

```
node --max-old-space-size=250 `which npm` install
```

Here we told node to limit RAM usage to 250Mo, the 'which npm' part gives the current npm path and 'install' is the script you want to run.

Comment: Probably I don’t need is anymore, but out of curiosity let’s say I have a typical npm project with a _package.json_ and I want to limit the CPU usage of the ```start``` script, I can navigate to the app directory and type ```node --max-old-space-size=250 npm start```.

Comment: @PDXIII Absolutly ! I currently have an automated deployment pipeline on a project that execute this command to avoid exceeding the maximum RAM usage amount allowed by a limited Docker container.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following and it works like a charm

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=50 npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is how you do it.**

You send a command to limit the ram usage.

```
npm install --max-old-space-size=400
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I described in my original post, I’ve tried that and it did not seem to work. But anyway I found a work around.

Comment: @tomexx I just didn’t. I worked around it. The project I wanted to build on the server I built it locally.

Comment: @PDXIII Ahh :( Thats a pity.

Answer (score 3):

To limit the CPU usage to 80%:

```
cpulimit -l 80 npm install
```

#### install

```
sudo apt-get install cpulimit # Debian based
# OR
sudo yum install cpulimit.    # REHL based
```

Comment: great to meet cpulimit command. Available on [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cpulimit) as well: `brew install cpulimit`. Unfortunately it doesn't work for a node.js process even using the `-i` option.